# Unsigned ints with json_decode() in PHP

Tags: php, int, json

I realize that PHP does not support unsigned integers, but I'm wondering how to solve this issue I'm having with json_decode(). When I decode JSON that contains unsigned ints above 2^31, they come out negative, since they are being treated as signed ints. Is this something I can rectify by configuring my php.ini file or is there just something about json_decode that I'm not getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The development version of PHP seems to have a planned option to [`json_decode()`](http://www.php.net/json_decode) exactly for this problem: `JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING` (see Example #5 in the manual) but there seems to be no production fix for this right now.

See also [this comment](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php#91785) in the user contributed notes.

Any chance of outputting strings on the encoding end somehow?

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that, thanks! Would you recommend any other json decoding techniques that might address this issue then?

Comment: @Nick I don't know of any that can explicitly deal with this. Creating strings on the encoding end might be easier, if it's feasible!

Comment: Thanks, I ended up just doing something similar to the encoding and it fixed my problem. I guess we'll just have to wait for a production fix at a later date!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PHP [BC Math extension](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php)!

> For arbitrary precision mathematics
>   PHP offers the Binary Calculator which
>   supports numbers of any size and
>   precision, represented as strings.